# Может ли часть сложного предложения быть детерминантом?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> После этого стали ломать здание: лопались окна **и** падали стены.

Если "да", может быть детерминантом, то верно ли, что можно не ставить запятую перед **и**?

Comment: Если не затруднит, то, пожалуйста, укажите ссылку на правило...

Comment: Меня смущает, что после двоеточия должны идти подробности (ломали окна и стены), а идет следствие (окна лопались и падали стены - здесь другое "действующее лицо"), то есть должно стоять тире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1) После этого стали ломать здание: (2)лопались окна и (3)падали стены.**

Как уже было отмечено, детерминант здесь ни при чем, так как он выделяется в простом предложении (в данном случае детерминантом  является "после этого" в предложении (1)).

Запятая не ставится, так как предложения (2) и (3) относятся **к общему предложению (1)**, между ними существует бессоюзная связь, которую можно обозначить двоеточием или тире.

**Двоеточие здесь вполне на  месте,** предложения (2) и (3) раскрывают тему, то есть наблюдатель описывает подробности разрушения.

Причинно-следственную связь (логическое обоснование) **можно обозначить тире**, если наблюдатель не видит происходящего, а только слышит шум, например: **После этого, должно быть,  стали ломать здание — звенели стекла  и  доносился  грохот падающих стен.**  Тире только обозначает сам факт причинно-следственной связи, не обозначая ее направления.

Однако и в этом случае можно поставить **двоеточие**, обозначив **направленность** связи как "вывод — факт" или "следствие — причина" (причина на втором месте: сообщается, почему наблюдатель сделал такой вывод).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ссылка на правило)**

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132

2. Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены **каким-либо общим элементом.**

Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложениия третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними **бессоюзной связью:** Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.); Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль (Купр.);

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, запятая перед *и* не ставится в любом случае ввиду наличия общего предложения в препозиции. Правило:

> В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:
>   <...>
>
> 2) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, **общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения**: Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал; **Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится (Щерб.)**; **Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.)**;
>
> [*Источник.*](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Во-вторых, по-моему, детерминант здесь — *после этого*. Только он не относится к какому-то определенному члену, а распространяет предложение в целом.

Детерминантом может быть и одно слово, и группа слов, но этот критерий не является определяющим: важно, чтобы он [детерминант] **не был связан лишь с одним членом предложения и соединялся с предложением с помощью связью свободного присоединения** («ослабленным» примыканием).

Не знаю, что бы посоветовать вам почитать в интернете. Наткнулся на эту статью: https://moluch.ru/archive/82/15067/. Вроде ничего ужасного в глаза не бросилось, хотя внимательно не читал.